# ReactJS, overlay video over image choosing a blend mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if there's a way to overlay a video over an image, but choosing how to blend them together.
As a reference, both Photoshop and Final Cut offer a lot of blending modes, like Overlay, Multiply, Add, and so on.

Maybe there's some library that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are also some overlay effects in css, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). I add an example, you can alter the `mix-blend-mode` to any of `overlay`, `screen`, etc.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#effet {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video id="effet" autoplay loop width="100%">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!